# Can I use Handsontable Pro without ejecting from create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, handsontable

I'd like to use Handsontable Pro with React. Installing the [official React wrapper](https://github.com/handsontable/react-handsontable) seems to [require editing webpack.config.js](https://github.com/handsontable/react-handsontable/wiki/Installation-guide#basic-installation) to work with the Pro version of the library.

This will require me to eject from create-react-app, which I don't want to do.

Is there a way around this?

One option could be to embed the scripts. If I embed the scripts directly (not ideal) do I only have to embed the Handsontable scripts and Babel/React can continue to be managed via npm and webpack?

Comment: Try this https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias By this library you can do the same configuration directly in package.json without ejecting webpack config.

Comment: Thanks. Will try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See what Dan Abramov writes here:
https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2608

He references this package:
https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired